# Long blog titles word-wrap on same line.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

A problem with word-wrapping of blog titles exists, where long titles will wrap onto the same line, or only about a half-line lower.

The below screenshot is from Firefox 5 on Windows XP Pro x86.  The problem appears identical on the following systems:

- Firefox 5, Windows XP Pro x86
- Firefox 5, Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- IE 7, Windows XP Pro x86
- Firefox 4, Windows 7 x64

[image]

The next screenshot is from Chromium on Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit.  (Thanks to @ThomasPornin)  Also applies to:

- Chromium, Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit
- Chrome, Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit
- Chrome, Windows XP x86
- Chrome, Windows 7 x64
- IE 9, Windows 7 x64

[image]

I checked the Blog Overflow homepage, to see if there were other sites that might have this problem.  But it seems ours is the only one with a post title that long, in recent history.

Comment: With Chromium there is a partial overlap; see http://www.bolet.org/blog-security.SE-screenshot.png

Comment: And with FireFox (any version) we get the overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the css, looks much better now.

And if you still see it messed up, blame caching and try again later. (:

Comment: No problems with caching - works fine on FF5, XP.  Thanks!

Comment: note to self: line-height: 1.3 <> line-height: 1.3px...